# Fixation rate at neutral loci

Tags: evolution, genetics, population-dynamics, population-biology, population-genetics

It is a classical result that the expected time for a neutral mutation to occur and to get fixed is $2 N \mu \frac{1}{2N} = \mu$, where $N$ is the population size and $\mu$ is the neutral mutation rate ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(population_genetics))).

I am not sure I understand what this actually mean. What is the probability of (at least) one fixation event to occur in $\frac{1}{\mu}$ generations? Is it 0.5? Could we calculate the probability that (at least) one fixation event occurs in $n$ generations? For example after $n=\frac{\mu}{10}$ generations, is the probability of observing (at least) one fixation event equal to $0.1$ or is it more complicated?

**UPDATE**

Following @DanielWeissman comments:

Let's consider we are starting with an initially monomorphic population (population of clones). In addition to that, let's consider that the population is relatively small $N\mu < 1$

Comment: You should probably specify whether you're considering an initially monomorphic population, or a steady-state population (with infinite alleles), or something else.

Comment: I didn't realize that would matter. Let's consider an initially monomorphic population. (see update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the $\mu$ is not expected time for a mutation to occur and get fixed; it is the rate at which mutations are fixed in the population. The basic result states that if neutral mutations arise at a locus at rate $\mu$ *within individuals*, mutations at this locus will be fixed *in the population* at rate $\mu$ as well.

The expected time for a given neutral mutation to fix after arising, given that it is not lost from the population, is approximately $4N_e$, where $N_e$ is the effective population size. [Kimura and Ohta (1969)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1212239/) derive this result using a diffusion approximation; [Kingman (1982)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414982900114) develops coalescent theory and in the process obtains what in my opinion is a more elegant derivation of the same approximation.

Now what is the probability that *some* mutation goes to fixation in the population as a function of time? Even though the fixation rate in the population is $\mu$, this does not mean that with probability 0.5 some mutation fixes within $1/\mu$ time units. That probability will depend on the distribution of fixation events in the population. Here's a good way to think about it. If fixation events were evenly spaced and occurred at rate $\mu$, then with probability 1 you would have a mutation within an interval of length $1/\mu$. If fixation events were highly clumped, then you would have a very low probability of having a fixation event within an interval of length $1/\mu$ -- but if you did have one event, you would probably have many. If fixation events are distributed as a Poisson process--which I suspect they would be in a purely neutral model--the probability of having a fixation event within a time interval $1/\mu$ would be given by a [(negative) exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) and thus the probability of having at least one fixation event in a time interval of length $1/\mu$ would be $1-\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: This final answer isn't quite correct -- it neglects the drift time mentioned in the second paragraph. If $N\mu \ll 1$ it's a good approximation though. (If $N\mu \gg 1$, the process of fixation is almost deterministic.)

Comment: @DanielWeissman Thank you for the informative correction.